# Length of stay in Schengen area

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration

I have a Schengen visa valid from July 7 until July 29 with a duration of stay of 8 days.

I am going to depart from Toronto to Stockholm on July 7. I'll arrive in Paris on July 8 and then in Stockholm on the same day. I am going to leave the Schengen area on July 15.

I was wondering whether it is considered as an overstay.

Answer (score 2):

If you only *arrive* in the Schengen area on the 8th, then you're just within the limit. There are 8 dates on which you are present in the Schengen area for any time: the 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th.

The plan doesn't leave much room for your return flight being delayed or canceled, though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "only arrive" ?

Comment: @Mohammad: It means "if you do not arrive in the Schengen area before the 8th ..."

Comment: Ah, No, I won't. But I heard from a colleague that in the Pearson airport they checked his VISA and didn't let him board while he was going to land in the Schengen area right at the beginning of the starting date of his VISA.

Comment: I mean even if I depart from Toronto on July 7, they might count that as 1 day since I am actually heading to Schengen area on that day.

Comment: @Mohammad it is not necessary to write the word *visa* in capital letters.

Comment: @Mohammad Are you transiting airside in Stockholm on 7th?

Comment: @Traveller What do you mean?

Comment: @Traveller I'll depart from Toronto on 7th and change my flight in Paris in 8th towards Stockholm.